# pyautogui - is there a way to typewrite in windows remote desktop session?

Tags: python, windows, rdp, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.click(x=221, y=699, interval=1) # remote desktop in windows panel
pyautogui.click(x=279, y=375, interval=1) # click on search bar in remote desktop browser
pyautogui.typewrite("dadasfasaf") # it does nothing in remote desktop session
```

is there a way to make script's job done? or other library with funcionality to write inside Windows remote desktop session? Thanks in advance

Comment: Clarification: start script from local windows machine, then click to icon in windows panel to open already estabilished windows remote desktop session -> click to browser search bar in remote dekstop -> and then I want to write into that search bar, but it seems that pyautogui cant write into RDP.. have you guys any workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

module **keyboard** solves the problem

```
keyboard.write("asdaf") # works fine
```